# How to respond to long click in listfragment

Tags: java, android

I was looking over the android developer documentation and I noticed that there is only a method for responding to clicks, how can I respond to long click in list fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getListView()` in your `ListFragment` to get the underlying list and then use the `setOnItemLongClickListener()` of the `ListView`.

Voila! :)